# Cannot return string from python class

Tags: python, string, class, repr

I'm trying to learn how to correctly use classes in python, I'm fairly new to it but I cant get this class to return a string output of all the values. Ideally I'd like to be able to just str(packet) into a network socket.

```
class ARP():
    dst_addr = ''
    src_addr = ''
    type = '\x08\x06'
    payload = '\x00\x01\x08\x00\x06\x04\x00'
    arptype = '\x01'
    src_mac_addr = ''
    src_ip_addr = ''
    dst_mac_addr = ''
    dst_ip_addr = ''

    def __repr_(self):
        return 'ARP'
    def __str__(self):
        return dst_addr + src_addr + type + payload + arptype \
            + src_mac_addr + src_ip_addr + dst_mac_addr + dst_ip_addr


p = ARP()
p.dst_addr = router_mac 
p.src_addr = random_mac()
p.arptype = '\x02'
p.src_mac_addr = local_mac
p.src_ip_addr = ip_s2n(target_ip)
p.dst_mac_addr = router_mac
p.dst_ip_addr = ip_s2n(router_ip)

print 'PACKET: ', str(p)
return str(p)
```

This code outputs nothing at all. `repr()` outputs `<__main__.ARP instance at 0x2844ea8>` which I guess is what it's meant to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an underscore in your `__repr__` method name:

```
def __repr_(self):
# ---------^
```

Python looks for `__repr__`, not `__repr_`.

Next, your `__str__` method should refer to attributes on `self`, not to globals. Perhaps a `str.join()` call would be helpful here too:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join([getattr(self, attr) for attr in (
        'dst_addr', 'src_addr', 'type', 'payload', 'arptype', 'src_mac_addr',
        'src_ip_addr', 'dst_mac_addr', 'dst_ip_addr')])
```

Comment: Also, your `__str__` isn't going to work because of all those undefined variables.

Comment: @kindall: ah, indeed, I somehow missed the utter lack of `self` in that method.